# MongoDB : Slow text search when searching a very frequent term

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of about 1 million documents (movies mainly), I created a text index on a field. All works fine for almost all searches : less than 20ms to have a result. The exception is when one search for a very frequent term, it can lasts up to 3000 ms !
For example,

if I search for 'pulp' in the collection (only 40 documents have it), it lasts 1ms

if I search for 'movie' (750 000 documents have it), it lasts 3000ms.
When profiling the request, the explain('executionStats') show that all 'movies' documents are scanned. I tried many indexing, sorting + limiting and hinting but all 750 000 documents are still scanned and the result is still slow to come...

Is there a strategy to be able to search very frequent term in a database faster ?

Comment: This is expected behaviour, think about it. A text index is much larger than the actual collection, because every word gets indexed. so searching through a part of the index that is bigger than the total collection will result in mongoDB to scan the actual collection itself. if you were able to force it to use the index, it would be even slower. To get results faster you could maybe limit the result?

Comment: I tried to limit, but as I want a sorted output, all docs are still scanned...logically.

Answer (score 0):

I ended to do my own stop words list by coding something like this :

```
import pymongo
from bson.code import Code

# NB max occurences of a word in a collection after what it is considerated as a stop word.
NB_MAX_COUNT = 20000
STOP_WORDS_FILE = 'stop_words.py'

db = connection to the database...

mapfn = Code("""function() {
    var words = this.field_that_is_text_indexed;
    if (words) {
        // quick lowercase to normalize per your requirements
        words = words.toLowerCase().split(/[ \/]/);
        for (var i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // might want to remove punctuation, etc. here
            if (words[i])  {      // make sure there's something
               emit(words[i], 1); // store a 1 for each word
            }
        }
    }
};""")

reducefn = Code("""function( key, values ) {
    var count = 0;
    values.forEach(function(v) {
        count +=v;
    });
    return count;
};""")

with open(STOP_WORDS_FILE,'w') as fh:
    fh.write('# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\n'
             'stop_words = [\n')

    result = db.mycollection.map_reduce(mapfn,reducefn,'words_count')
    for doc in result.find({'value':{'$gt':NB_MAX_COUNT}}):
        fh.write("'%s',\n" % doc['_id'])

    fh.write(']\n')
```